# private key on bsc network

Tags: python, private-key, web3py

i am using python with web3 for development. but it requires a private key, where can i find this private key.

i am using //bsc-data seed from binance RPC.

in ethereum there is infura...but in binance i cant figure out how to obtain this private key.

```
BSC RPC Endpoints:

    https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/
    https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s1.binance.org:8545/
    https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545/
    https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s2.binance.org:8545/
    https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s3.binance.org:8545/
    https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s3.binance.org:8545/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is  it a api key, you will find it once you log in on binance